# Using regular Expressions with Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am using Java Spring to work with Mongodb. I need to find documents which the word 'manager' is existed in description field. I tried following two method

Method 1

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("discription").regex("/\bmanager\b/"));
```

Method 2

```
Query query = new Query();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\bmanager\b/");
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("discription").regex(p));
```

But none of these were worked. I tried it with mongodb console like this

```
db.test.find({discription: {$regex: /\bmanager\b/}})
```

It worked as I expected. What's wrong with my Java code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add the slashes in the regex expression, as the regex method takes care of it. So

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("description").regex("\bmanager\b"));
```

should work.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. Have a look here: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-like-query-example/

Comment: Maybe you should use BasicQuery instead of query. Another way would be to use SpringData's repository feature.

Comment: I can get it work if I use regular expression as "manager" without enclosing it with '\b \b'. But that's not the result I expected. I want 'manager' as a whole word. I think the problem here is using '\b \b'

Comment: You might have to escape the slashes.

Comment: If I print the query object it looks like this. Query: { "description" : { "$regex" : "/\bmanager\b/"}}. The regular expression string has enclosed with double quotations here. That's the problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just pass your regex string straight through without using `Pattern.compile()`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: doh.  missed that.  is it really `discription` in the db and not `description`?

Comment: :) Just a typing mistake. It should be description.

Comment: But the problem is still exist

Comment: Yeah, i don't know spring-data so I'm not sure what else to suggest except step through how `regex()` works and see what the final generated query looks like.